# Modifying tuples

Tags: python, tuples

I am trying to modify my tuple with squares and roots but I get index out of range error and I honestly have no idea why it does not work as am fairly new to python.

```py
import math

a=int(input("min"))
b=int(input("max"))
oddList=[]
for i in range(a,b):
    if i%2!=0:
        oddList.append(i)
print(oddList)
k=tuple(oddList)
for i in k:
    newk=k[:i]+(2**k[i],math.sqrt(k[i]))+k[i:]
```

Comment: Where is this trying to modify a tuple (which can't be done, as it it immutable)?

Comment: Yeah I know that, but is there any sneaky way?

Comment: Why using a tuple?

Comment: Print out the `i` value. You'll see it's the odd numbers. Not an index for `k`

Comment: `oddList = list(range(a|1, b, 2))`. `a|1` "rounds up" to the nearest odd integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for i in k` has `i` range over the *contents* of `k`; you are using `i` as an *index* into `k`.